# Error while creating new envelope from existing envelope docusign

Tags: docusignapi, envelope

I am using C# docusign client v4.0 in my application.I am creating new envelope from existing envelope.

```
  var envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition
        {
            EmailSubject = "Email Subject",
            Status = "sent",
            EnvelopeId = envelopeId
        };
            var envelopeSummary = await envelopesApi.CreateEnvelopeAsync(await AccountAsync(), envDef);//this line gives error
```

`//"errorCode":"UNSPECIFIED_ERROR","message":"The value for column 'EnvelopeSourceTypeId' in table 'Envelope' is DBNull."`

Suddenly I am getting error while creating envelope from existing one.

```
Error calling CreateEnvelope: {"errorCode":"UNSPECIFIED_ERROR","message":"The value for column 'EnvelopeSourceTypeId' in table 'Envelope' is DBNull."}
```

Have anyone faced this issue? any suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, looks like we have a bug, which we're working on right now (internally we call this EC-1468). I'll update when we have it fixed. Also, looking for workarounds for you, we'll update here when I have something.

Comment: any idea how long does it take?ETC

Comment: not yet, I'll let you know. One other thing you can do for now - use a template instead of an envelope. That API works ok.

Comment: it was working fine for lower version..I arises when nuget version is updated

Comment: this is probably because lower version uses API 2.0 and newer uses API 2.1. You can use API 2.0 for now if that works for you